# Adding/Merging text in an image in the browser with PHP

Tags: php, html

I would like to do something like http://en.nametests.com/test/what-does-your-name-say-about-you/641/

Although, I couldn't get it to work. What html code do I need? Guide me please.

the  code I have right now is this

The problem is it won't give me an option to enter a name.

When the user enters in their name in the text field, it will generate an image with their own name on the image. The text will merge into the image. I don't know a better way to phrase this.

Please any tips, sugguestions, pros, cons?

```
<?php
  //Set the Content Type
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('sunset.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'font.TTF';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "This is a sunset!";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);

  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image);

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to learn how HTML forms work.

You will need to create HTML page with form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="your_script.php">
<input type="text" name="your_name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate image!" />
</form>
```

And then, in your_script.php, you put your prepared code and change line where the text is set to

```
$text = $_POST['your_name'];
```

Hope this is sufficient for you - if not, you should probably learn some HTML and PHP basics or find some pre-programmed solution.

Comment: so far I got the text field and the submit button to work.

Comment: Janocko Although, when I click "Generate Image!" It does not echo out the image at all. Yes I did link my "JPEG image" to it. What is the problem?

Comment: What is the address in browser after you click the Generate button? Is it the address of the script that generates image?

Comment: Yes!!

Btw, I added the code in wordpress pages... example:

http://thequizmania.com/test/